# Fixed distance between two points

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to make a function that receives a $x_b$ of a cartesian point and returns their $y_b$ in such a way that $d_{ab} = 16$.
The $(x_a, y_a)$ is a predefined point like $(2, 4)$

I already tried to do this with the following formula but I'm getting lost when I try to isolate the $y_b$ variable

$$d_{ab} = \sqrt {(x_b - x_a)^2 + (y_b - y_a)^2}$$
$$16 = \sqrt {(x_b  - 2)^2 + (y_b - 4)^2}$$

...

$${y_b}^2-8{y_b} = -{x_b}^2 + 4x_b + 252$$

Comment: Square both sides of the equation.

Comment: That's how you find the equation of a circle. Search it up.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I had already done this but forgot to explain it in the question, sorry. I updated the question with the exact part I'm having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to isolate $y_b$, just solve for it because it is a one-variable equation.

Assume $x_b = 8$,

then your equation becomes:

$16 = \sqrt{(8 - 2)^2 + (y_b - 4)^2}$

--> $16 = \sqrt{36 + (y_b - 4)^2}$

Now, square both sides:

$16^2 = \sqrt{36 + (y_b - 4)^2}^2$

--> $256 = 36 + (y_b - 4)^2$

--> $220 = (y_b - 4)^2$

--> $\sqrt{220} = y_b - 4$

$\therefore y_b = \sqrt{220} + 4$

or simplfied to $2\sqrt{55} + 4$

or to 4 decimal: $18.8324$

**EDIT**:

If $x_b$ stays a `variable`, then:

$16 = \sqrt{(x_b - 2)^2 + (y_b - 4)^2}$

Now, square both sides:

$16^2 = \sqrt{(x_b - 2)^2 + (y_b - 4)^2}^2$

--> $256 = (x_b - 2)^2 + (y_b - 4)^2$

--> $256 - (x_b - 2)^2 = (y_b - 4)^2$

--> $\pm\sqrt{256 - (x_b - 2)^2} = y_b - 4$

$\therefore y_b = \pm\sqrt{256 - (x_b - 2)^2} + 4$

[image: Circle Image]

As seen $y_b$ will always have $2$ $x_b$ values (`+` and `-`), expect for `y = 20 or y = -12`.

Comment: I think it's useful to isolate the variable because I can generalize to other values as well. I will use this equation in a script for generating a data visualization

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer, but the same equation rules still apply though